# I need a way to can use a image as camera input in android phone

Tags: android

Hi i need a way to can use image from gallery as camera input . IT need to be as default so when other apps open camera will get by default the image from the gallery. I know there are apps in marketplace but they are ask first from where to get the input . I need Something that will show by default the image from gallery as camera input.

Comment: If that is possible on non-rooted devices, that would represent a fairly significant security flaw.

Comment: Ok . I cant root the phone but is any way to set default image as camera input and how?

Comment: I can root this phone without issue